# Setting up https on Zabbix

Tags: https, zabbix

I am trying to set up https on Zabbix dashboard website based on server ip address, for example: https://10.x.x.x/zabbix

Feeling not secure enough when login to Zabbix dashboard with out https
Does anyone know how to set up https for zabbix?

Answer (score 0):

You set HTTPS on the webserver, not the application itself:

- Apache: https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/apache-openssl.htm
- Nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html